# mapping 2 directories linux-server

Tags: linux, .htaccess, ubuntu, webserver

I have a website mydomain.com. The parent directory contains (among others) httpdocs and web_users. web_users contains a folder myFolder.

I made a symbolic link (ln -s) to httpdocs, all went well. But now, when I try to go to mydomain.com/myFolder, I get an error:

> Forbidden You do not have permission to access this document.
>
> Web Server at mydomain.com

How can I make this work? Do I have to adjust my .htaccess?

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a file permission problem. Be sure that your web server user(www-data or httpd usually) has read permissions on your myFolder directory.

Comment: How can I check this? my /etc/passwd only has one user: myuser.com:x:10003:1005::/:/bin/bash

Comment: Well, I checked myFolder permissions and found that it is in the wrong group. But now I want to change the owner but command line does not understand the chown command (command not found).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1, Be sure to have enabled

```
Option FollowSymLinks
```

Docs : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#Options

2, Be sure that apache process have read permissions to your directory, try to

```
chmod 0777 myFolder
```

to your folder or

```
chown [apacheuser] myFolder
```

this should fix it

Comment: My .htaccess has Options +FollowSymlinks enabled.
myFolder has drwxr-xr-x permissions.